# Cocos2d-x shader scene transition effect not working as expected on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, glsl, cocos2d-x, glsles

I'm working on my very first game and I'm finally at the end of development, but I've run into a small problem with one of my shaders. I'm not very good at working with shaders at all, so my ability to solve problems related to them is still very limited.

Anyways, it's an effect that tries to mimic a scene transition often found in cartoons, or sometimes mario games. The screen is filled with black with a transparent whole in it, that gets smaller and smaller until the whole screen is black (or the reverse).

On windows, it works as intented, but when I try to run it on my phone (iPhone6s), the effect is cut off as soon as the circle touches the screen edge (see image for reference).

[image]

What do you think could be the problem? If it cannot be solved with a shader, do you know of any workarounds that would work the same visually?

Oh, almost forgot, here's the shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
   precision mediump float;
#endif

const float scale = 1.0;

uniform float uAlpha;
uniform int isActive;
uniform float centerPtX;
uniform float centerPtY;
uniform float uCircleRadius;
uniform vec2 uResolution;

varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

vec2 getCoordinates()
{
    return vec2(
        v_texCoord.x * uResolution.x, 
        v_texCoord.y * uResolution.y
    );
}

float getDist(vec2 pt1, vec2 pt2)
{
    float dx = pt1.x - pt2.x;
    float dy = pt1.y - pt2.y;

    return sqrt((dx*dx) + (dy*dy));
}

void main()
{       
    if (isActive == 0) // don't draw anything
    {
        gl_FragColor = v_fragmentColor;
        return;
    }

    vec3 finalCol = vec3(0.0);
    vec3 circleCol = vec3(1.0);
    vec2 centerPt = vec2(centerPtX, centerPtY);
    float dis = length(getCoordinates() - centerPt);

    // outline
    //circleCol += 1.0 * smoothstep(uCircleRadius * 0.95, uCircleRadius, dis);

    // render
    finalCol = circleCol.zyx * (1.0 - smoothstep(uCircleRadius * 0.99, uCircleRadius, dis));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(finalCol.rgb, uAlpha);
}
```

Comment: The fact that the shader effect is working in Windows but misbehaving in iOS makes me think the problem is probably outside the shader. Most likely it's application logic. It is also possibly (but extremely unlikely) a bug in the driver.

Comment: There's not really anything wrong with the shader logic as far as I can see other than the possibility of rounding errors introduced by floating point operations. If you're getting different behaviour on different platforms it has to be down to the the uniforms you're passing in. As @Xirema says this is likely a problem in your application logic.

Comment: I see. I'll have to look over everything again carefully. Thanks!